# Solution to IVP for ODE

Tags: calculus

ODE: $ 2tx'(t)-1=x^2(t) $

If I have the general solution:

$2 \arctan(x) = \ln(t) + C $

And I have the initial condition $ x(t=1) =1 $ then:

$2 \arctan(1) = \ln(1) + C $

$ \frac{\pi}{2} = C $

I just found C but I still need the solution to the IVP, right? How do I go from here?

Hope you can help!

Comment: Where is the ODE?

Comment: Sorry, it is 2tx'(t)-1=x^2(t). I will add it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you found that $C=\frac{\pi}{2}$, and that your ODE solution is
$$2 \arctan(x) = \ln(t) + C,$$
then the solution to your IVP is just the same but using the value of $C$ you just found:
$$\boxed{2 \arctan(x) = \ln(t) + \frac{\pi}{2}},$$
and this would be an $\underline{\text{implicit}}$ solution to your IVP. Now, if what you're asking for is the $\underline{\text{explicit}}$ solution, the you just have to transform it into the form you like, to be said:
$$\arctan(x)=\frac{\ln(t)}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}$$
$$\Downarrow$$
$$\boxed{x=\arctan^{-1}\left(\frac{\ln(t)}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you! Just to be sure about I'm using the right terminology: Is "explicit solution" the same as a "particular solution", and "general solution" the same as "implicit solution"?

Comment: @Claire21 Your welcome! And no, they're not the same. "Explicit" means that the expression is of the form $x(t) = f(t)$, and "implicit" means it's for example given in the form $g(x(t))=f(t)$. Do you understand? I can explain it a bit better if necessary. "General" and "particular" terms have nothing to do with explicitness and implicitness.